# How to create a mockable class to connect to mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I've tried to create a class to connect to a mongoDB (and get a gridFS connection using (`gridfs-stream`). But with that I do get two problems:

1. I do get sometimes the mongo Error `server instance in invalid state connected`
2. It is impossible for me to mock this class out - using jestJS

So I would be very thankful if someone can help me to optimize this class to get a really solid working class. For example I don't like the `let that = this` in the connect() function.

[Example repo](https://github.com/jaqua/mongodb-class)

**DB class**

```
const mongo = require('mongodb')
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream')
const { promisify } = require('util')

export default class Db {
  constructor (uri, callback) {
    this.db = null
    this.gfs = null
    const server = process.env.MONGO_SERVER || 'localhost'
    const port = process.env.MONGO_PORT || 27017
    const db = process.env.MONGO_DB || 'test'

    // Is this the correct way to connect (using mongo native driver)?
    this.connection = new mongo.Db(db, new mongo.Server(server, port))
    this.connection.open = promisify(this.connection.open)
    this.connected = false
    return this
  }

  async connect (msg) {
    let that = this
    if (!this.db) {
      try {
        await that.connection.open()
        that.gfs = Grid(that.connection, mongo)
        this.connected = true
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('mongo connection error', err)
      }
    }
    return this
  }

  isConnected () {
    return this.connected
  }
}
```

**Example**

This function will add a new user to the DB using the class above:

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import Db from './lib/db'
const db = new Db()

export async function createUser (obj, { username, password }) {
  if (!db.isConnected()) await db.connect()
  const Users = db.connection.collection('users')
  return Users.insert({
    username,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10),
    createdAt: new Date()
  })
}
```

**Unit test**

I need to create a unit test to test if the mongoDB method is called. No integration test for testing the method.
So I need to mock the DB connection, collection and insert method.

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import { createUser } from '../../user'

import Db from '../../lib/db'
const db = new Db()
jest.mock('bcrypt')

describe('createUser()', () => {
  test('should call mongoDB insert()', async () => {
    bcrypt.hashSync = jest.fn(() => SAMPLE.BCRYPT)
    // create somekind of mock for the insert method...
    db.usersInsert = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ _id: '507f1f77bcf86cd799439011' }))
    await createUser({}, {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    }).then((res) => {
      // test if mocked insert method has been called
      expect(db.usersInsert).toHaveBeenCalled()
      // ... or better test for the returned promise value
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: As of now you are asking if your approach is right or you get an error running these tests?

Comment: Can you tell which actual DB class you are using? The issue is clear with your mock, you don't mock the connect methods in `db.js` and `db.connect = jest.fn()`, the mock would return an undefined value. Also manual mocks needs to be explicitly called in your test as per documentation, https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html, `When we require that module in our tests, then explicitly calling jest.mock('./moduleName') is required.`.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've added the class to the post. And I'm using mongodb native driver.

Comment: Does your `user.js` work as of now? Because I see you return `this` and there is no collections method there? Which means leave the testing part your code itself is not working as of now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167230/discussion-between-user3142695-and-tarun-lalwani).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go about this. I will list few of them

- Mock the DB class using a Jest manual mock. This could be cumbersome if you are using too many mongo functions. But since you are encapsulating most through the DB class it may still be manageable
- Use a mocked mongo instance. [This](https://github.com/williamkapke/mongo-mock) project allows you to simulate a MongoDB and persist data using js file
- Use a [in-memory](https://github.com/hemerajs/mongo-memory) mongodb
- Use a actual mongodb

I will showcase the first case here, which you posted about with code and how to make it work. So first thing we would do is update the `__mocks__/db.js` file to below

```
jest.mock('mongodb');
const mongo = require('mongodb')
var mock_collections = {};
var connectError = false;
var connected = false;
export default class Db {
    constructor(uri, callback) {
        this.__connectError = (fail) => {
            connected = false;
            connectError = fail;
        };

        this.clearMocks = () => {
            mock_collections = {};
            connected = false;
        };

        this.connect = () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                process.nextTick(
                    () => {
                        if (connectError)
                            reject(new Error("Failed to connect"));
                        else {
                            resolve(true);
                            this.connected = true;
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
        };

        this.isConnected = () => connected;

        this.connection = {
            collection: (name) => {
                mock_collections[name] = mock_collections[name] || {
                    __collection: name,
                    insert: jest.fn().mockImplementation((data) => {
                        const ObjectID = require.requireActual('mongodb').ObjectID;

                        let new_data = Object.assign({}, {
                            _id: new ObjectID()
                        },data);
                        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                process.nextTick(
                                    () =>
                                        resolve(new_data))
                            }
                        );
                    })
                    ,
                    update: jest.fn(),
                    insertOne: jest.fn(),
                    updateOne: jest.fn(),
                };
                return mock_collections[name];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now few explanations

- `jest.mock('mongodb');` will make sure any actual mongodb call gets mocked
- The `connected`, `connectError`, `mock_collections` are global variables. This is so that we can impact the state of the `Db` that your `user.js` loads. If we don't do this, we won't be able to control the mocked `Db` from within our tests
- `this.connect` shows how you can return a promise and also how you can simulate a error connecting to DB when you want
- `collection: (name) => {` makes sure that your call to `createUser` and your test can get the same collection interface and check if the mocked functions were actually called.
- `insert: jest.fn().mockImplementation((data) => {` shows how you can return data by creating your own implementation
- `const ObjectID = require.requireActual('mongodb').ObjectID;` shows how you can get an actual module object when you have already mocked `mongodb` earlier

Now comes the testing part. This is the updated `user.test.js`

```
jest.mock('../../lib/db');
import Db from '../../lib/db'
import { createUser } from '../../user'

const db = new Db()

describe('createUser()', () => {
  beforeEach(()=> {db.clearMocks();})

  test('should call mongoDB insert() and update() methods 2', async () => {
    let User = db.connection.collection('users');
    let user = await createUser({}, {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    });
    console.log(user);
    expect(User.insert).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

    test('Connection failure', async () => {
        db.__connectError(true);
        let ex = null;
        try {
          await createUser({}, {
          username: 'username',
          password: 'password'
        })
      } catch (err) {
        ex= err;
      }
      expect(ex).not.toBeNull();
      expect(ex.message).toBe("Failed to connect");
    })
})
```

Few pointers again

- `jest.mock('../../lib/db');` will make sure that our manual mock gets loaded
- `let user = await createUser({}, {` since you are using `async`, you will not use `then` or `catch`. That is the point of using `async` function.
- `db.__connectError(true);` will set the global variable `connected` to `false` and `connectError` to true. So when `createUser` gets called in the test it will simulate a connection error
- `ex= err;`, see how I capture the exception and take out the expect call. If you do expect in the `catch` block itself, then when an exception is not raised the test will still pass. That is why I have done exception testing outside the `try/catch` block

Now comes the part of testing it by running `npm test` and we get

[image: Jest test results]

All of it is committed to below repo you shared

https://github.com/jaqua/mongodb-class

Answer (score 1):

You are stubbing on an instance of DB, not the actual DB class. Additionally I don't see the `db.usersInsert` method in your code. We can't write your code for you, but I can point you in the right direction. Also, I don 't use Jest but the concepts from Sinon are the same. The best thing to do in your case I believe is to stub out the prototype of the class method that returns an object you are interacting with.

Something like this:

```
// db.js
export default class Db {
  getConnection() {}
}

// someOtherFile.js
import Db from './db';

const db = new Db();
export default async () => {
  const conn = await db.getConnection();
  await connection.collection.insert();
}

// spec file
import {
  expect
} from 'chai';
import {
  set
} from 'lodash';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import Db from './db';
import testFn from './someOtherFile';


describe('someOtherFile', () => {
  it('should call expected funcs from db class', async () => {
    const spy = sinon.spy();
    const stub = sinon.stub(Db.prototype, 'getConnection').callsFake(() => {
      return set({}, 'collection.insert', spy);
    });
    await testFn();
    sinon.assert.called(spy);
  });
});
```